# IIS slow in loading Report Viewer

Tags: c#, iis, reporting-services, reportviewer

We are running IIS & SSRS on the same production server and have two types of reports - one running through Report Viewer, connecting to SSRS (remote mode) and the other calling the SSRS web service to generate PDFs.

For both of the report types, it becomes very slow when loading the page, taking upwards of 20 seconds. It is most evident during periods of heavy server load and the slowness will go away after recycling the application pool in IIS but comes back after a while (the application pool is set to recycle daily at 3am).

I have checked the execution log of SSRS - for all the reports the time for data retrieval + processing + rendering will take no more than 2 seconds and the http logs of SSRS indicate that there is no request from IIS when the page becomes unresponsive - once the request does reach it loads very quickly.
The reports when run through the report manager are very fast also.

It does not seem like SSRS is the culprit here and seems like something in IIS is causing it.

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem or can point me in the right direction for diagnosing?

Many thanks.

---

**ReportViewer:**

```
public abstract class ReportPageBase : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void GenerateReport(ReportViewer reportViewer)
    {
        var reportParameters = new List<ReportParameter>();

        reportViewer.Visible = true;

        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(Util.ReportServerUrl);
        reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials();

        ParametersOverride(ref reportParameters);
        reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
    }

    protected abstract void ParametersOverride(ref List<ReportParameter> reportParameters);
}
```

**Web service:**

```
public static class ReportExporter
{
    public static Stream GetExportStream(string reportName, string format, ReportExecutionService.ParameterValue[] paramVals)
    {
        var rs = new ReportingService2005SoapClient();
        var rsExec = new ReportExecutionServiceSoapClient();

        var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerUser"];
        var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerPassword"];
        var domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerDomain"];
        var folderPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportViewerFoler"];
        System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

        rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;
        rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = networkCredential;

        rs.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
        rsExec.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;

        var _reportName = (folderPath ?? @"/") + reportName.Trim();

        string historyID = null;

        // gets the parameters
        rs.GetReportParameters(_reportName, historyID, forRendering, values, credentials, out parameters);

        // load the report
        ExecutionInfo executionInfo = null;
        ReportExecutionService.ServerInfoHeader serverInfoHeader = null;

        ExecutionHeader header = new ExecutionHeader();
        rsExec.LoadReport(null, _reportName, historyID, out serverInfoHeader, out executionInfo);
        header.ExecutionID = executionInfo.ExecutionID;

        rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(header, null, paramVals, "en-us", out executionInfo);

        byte[] result = null;
        string[] streamIds = null;
        string encoding = String.Empty;
        string mimeType = String.Empty;
        string extension = String.Empty;
        ReportExecutionService.Warning[] warnings = null;

        rsExec.Render(header,
                      null,
                      format,
                      null,
                      out result,
                      out extension,
                      out mimeType,
                      out encoding,
                      out warnings,
                      out streamIds);

        var memstream = new MemoryStream(result);

        return memstream;
    }
}
```

Comment: We have similar problems. Did you find something?

Comment: @RonnyElfleinr11lein No, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi guys, did you find the problem? same here :(
We migrated our server to SSRS 2017 Standard (from SSRS 2008 Enterprise) and this issue started to happen. reportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters takes now 8-10 seconds instead of milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In my case.  IIS Express was very quick.  But in IIS 8.5 unacceptable slow !
My Solution:

- Create a new Application Pool eg. ".NET CLR Version v4.0.30319", "Classic"
- Change in the web the Application pool to the new one.